# dhclient "Can't bind to dhcp address" error

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, dhcp

I keep getting the following error message from dhclient upon starting of the Network Manager:

> Can't bind to dhcp address: Cannot assign requested address. Please
>   make sure there is no other dhcp server running and that there's no
>   entry for dhcp or bootp in /etc/inetd.conf.   Also make sure you are
>   not running HP JetAdmin software, which includes a bootp server.
>
> This version of ISC DHCP is based on the release available on
>   ftp.isc.org.  Features have been added and other changes have been
>   made to the base software release in order to make it work better with
>   this distribution.
>
> Please report for this software via the Red Hat Bugzilla site:
>   http://bugzilla.redhat.com

As far as I am aware, I don't have a dhcp server running, neither is there a file inetd.conf in /etc, also I am not running HP JetAdmin. I tried searching the internet, but can't find a solution. Neither do I fully understand this error message. Can somebody help me?

As requested. these are the output from the various commands:

```
# tcpdump -i wlp0s11u1u3 -n -w dhcp.pcap
tcpdump: listening on wlp0s11u1u3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
tcpdump: pcap_loop: The interface went down
10 packets captured
11 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

# tcpdump -n -r dhcp.pcap
reading from file dhcp.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
IP6 fe80::226:75ff:feb5:94a2 > ff02::1: ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
IP6 fe80::226:75ff:feb5:94a2 > ff02::1: ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35
STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.00:26:73:c5:90:d1.8005, length 35

ss -lntp
State     Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN    0      50                  *:3306             *:*      users:(("mysqld",1783,16))
LISTEN    0      128                 *:111              *:*      users:(("rpcbind",636,9))
LISTEN    0      128                 *:22               *:*      users:(("sshd",839,3))
LISTEN    0      128         127.0.0.1:631              *:*      users:(("cupsd",2454,11))
LISTEN    0      128                 *:39104            *:*      users:(("rpc.statd",843,9))
LISTEN    0      128                :::58379           :::*      users:(("rpc.statd",843,11))
LISTEN    0      128                :::111             :::*      users:(("rpcbind",636,12))
LISTEN    0      128                :::80              :::*      users:(("httpd",1915,3),("httpd",1914,3),("httpd",1913,3),("httpd",1912,3),("httpd",1911,3),("httpd",829,3))
LISTEN    0      128                :::22              :::*      users:(("sshd",839,4))
LISTEN    0      128               ::1:631             :::*      users:(("cupsd",2454,10))
LISTEN    0      128                :::443             :::*      users:(("httpd",1915,4),("httpd",1914,4),("httpd",1913,4),("httpd",1912,4),("httpd",1911,4),("httpd",829,4))
```

I think it has something to do with IPv6 which is currently not supported by my ISP.

Comment: please open two root shell windows: In one type 'tcpdump -i eth0 -n -w dhcp.pcap'.  In the other type '/etc/init.d/networking restart'.  Please hit cntl-c on the tcpdump after getting the error again, and add the output of 'tcpdump -n -r dhcp.pcap' to your question.

Comment: Please post the output of sudo ss -lntp.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, it is done.

Comment: @MikePennington, I have updated my question with the output.

Comment: Your outputs look just fine. The problem with this error message is that it is not specific at all. What kind of interface is wlp0s11u1u3? I thought it was a wifi IF. If it is, why are you using dhclient?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, it is a wireless USB adaptor. The device name is assigned by NetworkManager. I am not sure why it is given such a name too. I have set the DNS manually to point to Google. Not sure if that is the reason for dhclient.